# Form Submit Not Being Detected By isset

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to detect a form click using `if(isset($_POST['appSelecter'])){` however it seems to not be returning true. This might be to do with the fact that my button click returns to the same page which would loose the form data i had just populated. Can someone confirm if my assumption is correct and if so - how would i need to change this?

Thanks

**tried to only paste a sample piece of code to not confuse matters - seems i have made things worse - here is the full flow**

```
    <?php
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--META-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Client Portal Login</title>

<!--STYLESHEETS-->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Slider-in icons-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".username").focus(function() {
        $(".user-icon").css("left","-48px");
    });
    $(".username").blur(function() {
        $(".user-icon").css("left","0px");
    });

    $(".password").focus(function() {
        $(".pass-icon").css("left","-48px");
    });
    $(".password").blur(function() {
        $(".pass-icon").css("left","0px");
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<!--WRAPPER-->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!--SLIDE-IN ICONS-->
    <div class="user-icon"></div>
    <div class="pass-icon"></div>
    <!--END SLIDE-IN ICONS-->

<!--LOGIN FORM-->
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="index.php" method="post">

    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="header">
    <!--TITLE--><h1>Client Portal Login</h1><!--END TITLE-->
    <!--DESCRIPTION--><span>Please login to your client portal</span><!--END DESCRIPTION-->
    </div>
    <!--END HEADER-->

    <!--CONTENT-->
    <div class="content">
    <!--USERNAME--><input name="username" type="text" class="input username" value="Username" onfocus="this.value=''" /><!--END USERNAME-->
    <!--PASSWORD--><input name="password" type="password" class="input password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value=''" /><!--END PASSWORD-->
    </div>
    <!--END CONTENT-->

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <div class="footer">
    <!--LOGIN BUTTON--><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" /><!--END LOGIN BUTTON-->
    <!--REGISTER BUTTON--><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="register" /><!--END REGISTER BUTTON-->
    </div>
    <!--END FOOTER-->

</form>

<?php

include("application.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $userid = logUserIn($username, $password);
    if($userid > 0){
        $applicationsForUser = getAppInformation($userid);
        printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applicationsForUser);

        if(isset($_POST['appSelecter'])) {
            echo "this is a test message";
        }
    }
}


function printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applicationsForUser){
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    foreach ($applicationsForUser as $app) {        
        ?>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $app->getUserid(); ?>">  
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $app->getName(); ?>">  
            <input type="hidden" name="created" value="<?php echo $app->getDateCreated(); ?>">  
            <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $app->getInvoice(); ?>">  
            <input type="hidden" name="comment" value="<?php echo $app->getComment(); ?>">  
            <input type="submit" name="appSelecter" value="<?php echo $app->getName(); ?>">
        </form>
        <?php


    }
}


function getAppInformation($userid){
    $applicationsForUser = array();
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'clientportal');
    if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        //we have connected to the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE userid = '$userid'";
        if(!$val = $conn->query($sql)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }else{
            $index = 0;
            while($row = $val->fetch_assoc()){
                $userid = $row['userid'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $dateCreated = $row['date'];
                $invoice = $row['invoiceid'];
                $comment = $row['commentsid'];              
                $application = new Application($userid, $name, $dateCreated, $invoice, $comment);
                $applicationsForUser[$index] = $application;
                $index++;
            }
        }
    }
    $conn -> close();   
    return $applicationsForUser; 
}

function logUserIn($username, $password) {

    if(!isset($username) && !isset($password)){
        return -1;
    }

    $result = -1;
    //$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'web214-admin-ava', 'secondstory');
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'clientportal');
    if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        //we have connected to the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        if(!$val = $conn->query($sql)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }else{
            while($row = $val->fetch_assoc()){
                $result = $row['id'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $conn -> close();
    return $result;
}


?>

<!--END LOGIN FORM-->

</div>
<!--END WRAPPER-->

<!--GRADIENT--><div class="gradient"></div><!--END GRADIENT-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your logic inside a function? Unpredictable code

Comment: No quotes around the `value` attribute of the last input? And that `onClick="location.href='index.php'"` probably prevents the form from being sent, remove that

Comment: well spotted, didn't make any difference though

Comment: @Biscuit128 : How the `$_POST` value comes inside the function.

Comment: both POSTs will not happen at the same time, so this is wrong approach.

Comment: After login you have to save permanently your userid or something. That can be done using $_SESSION. And your appSelecter form looks useless, because it only contains hidden fields and submit button ... useless.

Answer (score 2):

You have used folowing in the form submit:

```
onClick="location.href='index.php'" // Making a GET request
```

This is not submitting the form using `POST` method. Remove this and it'll work.

**Update:** There is no `submit` button with name `submit` so this condion will not work:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Make it:

```
if(isset($_POST['appSelecter']))
```

You don't need `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead use;

```
if(isset($_POST['appSelecter'])) {

    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $userid = logUserIn($username, $password);

    if($userid > 0){
        $applicationsForUser = getAppInformation($userid);
        printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applicationsForUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also mention the `$_POST` check should not be inside the function

Comment: still doesn't seem to work I am afraid - the button gets clicked, the page refreshes yet nothing is echoed to the page

Comment: Are you calling the function `printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applicationsForUser)` in this page ? If you don't call the function then it won't work.

Comment: yes - let me paste the full code to the original post

Comment: 1. remove onClick from submit button.

Comment: 2. add quotes `"` around value on submit button.

Comment: the submit button is for another form, the idea here is that when someone logs in they can see x number of links/buttons for the apps they own. when they click one of these buttons a check takes place to see which it is and then based on that go and grab some more data

Comment: Only one form could be submitted at a time so nested checks for form submissions won't work, not sure about your idea but it doesn't sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

You dont nee this

```
onClick="location.href='index.php'"
```

dont do anything , just apply value to button i, i think you have applied already ,

by `location.href`  your request will be send by GET Method in thgis case no form elements sent to the server

if you allow native form submission then all form elements will be sent to server, in case of multiple forms , the only elements sent realted to that submit button form thats it